# Storing multilingual user entered text in Flutter app

Tags: java, mysql, flutter

The default language of my flutter app is English but I want to let the user enter text (such as their name) in their language (as supported by their phone) into a flutter TextField. This value is being saved in a mysql db table through REST API calls to the server implemented in Java (Springboot). The charset and collation of the db are: utf8mb4 and  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

The problem is when the data is read back from the db and displayed in the app in Text widget, it does not show up as expected. It is displayed in weird chars such as à¤¨à¤®à.

When I display the value in mysql command line tool using a select query, the value is shown as ????. Does that mean the data is stored incorrectly? I am not sure where is the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: this problem involves 3 parties: flutter, spring & mysql, to narrow it, can you not use flutter but use spring to load & display data as a REST and use browser to check the outcome?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think I found out the problem. The issue was that flutter was converting http response to JSON without using utf8. I replaced json.decode(httpResponse.body); with json.decode(utf8.decode(httpResponse.bodyBytes)); and it worked!